# Extract path from KML

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, path, kml

I need to extract a path I created in an KML file in Google Earth, I'd prefer using the Google Maps API to do so but I am still open to other options.

Comment: When we did this with our project, we used C# because it was easier than using Javascript, but you could use PHP and do it just as easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do that through the Google Maps API v3. Instead, you'd either need to use a server-side solution or use [GeoXML3](http://code.google.com/p/geoxml3/).